# How to switch from default maven antelink repository

Tags: maven

Over the past couple of days I get 503 error while accessing http://maven.antelink.com and my build fails because of that, I tried looking setting.xml which do not have the above url configured anywhere, how can I switch to an alternate mirror and which mirror is valid.

```
ERROR
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project core: Could not resolve dependencies f
or project **.***.*******:core:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could n
ot be resolved: com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.0, com.faste
rxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.0, com.fasterxml.jackson.module:ja
ckson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.6.0, com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jax
rs-xml-provider:jar:2.6.0, com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-x
ml:jar:2.6.0, org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4, org.codehaus.woodstox:w
oodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1: Could not transfer artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.co
re:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.0 from/to antelink.com (http://maven.antelink.com/co
ntent/repositories/central/): Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP resp
onse code: 503 for URL: http://maven.antelink.com/content/repositories/central/c
om/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.0/jackson-databind-2.6.0.jar from
 http://maven.antelink.com/content/repositories/central/com/fasterxml/jackson/co
re/jackson-databind/2.6.0/jackson-databind-2.6.0.jar -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
<mirror>
<id>uk.maven.org</id>
<mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
 <url>http://uk.maven.org/maven2</url>
</mirror>
```

at the end of settings.xml inside the  Tag